# html2canvas javascript screenshot pass to python

Tags: javascript, python, django, screenshot, html2canvas

would it be possible to use html2canvas to take a picture of the user`s screen but also i wanna use this image with python function. What I want to do is save the image of the html element with javascript and send it to slack with python.

```
 function capture() {
          html2canvas(document.getElementById("main"), {
              letterRendering: 1,
              allowTaint: true,
              useCORS: true,
          })
              .then(function (canvas) {
                  document.getElementById("result").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.5);
              })
              .catch((e) => {
                  alert(e);
              });
      }
```

Comment: Just write the file to disk and execute your python script?

Comment: how can i do this? @skara9

Comment: Is the python running on your computer?

Comment: @skara9 its working on server, i wanna save this image and send post request via python. Saving image to pc its will not work probely i think cause there is different users

Comment: You need to set up a post endpoint in django to receive the image file and make an ajax call to it in your javascript, so that you can send the image from your js to py.

Comment: your comments are not helping me im already know i should use ajax call but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) function to convert the canvas image into a `Blob` that you can send through `fetch`.

```js
.then(function (canvas) {
  canvas.toBlob(blob => {
    fetch("URL", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' }
      body: blob
    })
  
    const imgSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.getElementById("result").onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(imgSrc);
    document.getElementById("result").src = imgSrc;
  }, "image/png", 0.5)
});
```

Comment: thank u so much for help, i will try this

Answer (score 0):

i resolved problem like that;

JS;

```
<script>
      function capture() {
          html2canvas(document.getElementById("main"), {
              letterRendering: 1,
              allowTaint: true,
              useCORS: true,
          })
              .then(function (canvas) {
                  document.getElementById("result").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.5);
                  var img = canvas.toDataURL();
                  $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "{% url 'sendtoslack' %}",
                  data: { 
                  "imageData": img,
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                  }
                  
              })
              })
              .catch((e) => {
                  alert(e);
              });
      }
  </script>
```

view;

```
image = request.POST.get('imageData')
```

decoding base64;

```
import base64

imagestr = str(image)
x = imagestr[22:]
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(bytes(x, "utf-8"))))
```